# webdriver.io - click on specific element where many elements exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver

I have many elements with a class name on a page. Can I use webdriver.io to click on a specific one in the array of Web Elements?

If I do

```
browser
.elements("perc-val")
.then(function(res){

})
```

I get an array of JSON objects. Can I call any further functions on these such as `click()`, or `setKeys()`?

Comment: Tryng to add `webdriver-io` tag but failed :( can you add please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.

```
browser
 .elements("perc-val")
 .then(function(res){
    browser.click(res.val.element); // 
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm managing with version `4.8.0` of webdriver.io using `elementIdClick`

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } };
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);

client.elements(".button")
   .then(res => res.value.map(btn => client.elementIdClick(btn.ELEMENT)));
```

Where:

You must look at `value` property of the returned object for the list of elements.

- elements: [Returns a list of json objects where `.ELEMENT`is the id](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html)
- elementIdClick: [Executes the action of click given an id](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elementIdClick.html)